# Show remove buttons - DropzoneJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropzone.js

I am having problem showing Remove buttons on the thumbnails.

```
    var myDropzone = new Dropzone("#my-awesome-dropzone");

    myDropzone.options = {
        addRemoveLinks: true,
    };
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing to different ways of initializing dropzone, the simplest way is to use either one:

```
Dropzone.options.MyAwesomeDropzone = {
    addRemoveLinks: true
}
```

or the other

```
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

var myDropzone = new Dropzone("#my-awesome-dropzon", { 
    addRemoveLinks: true
});
```

Comment: any chance you know how to use removeAllFiles(true) with a jquery instantiation $('#myDrop').dropzone({...}); All I'm seeing is by using myDropzone.removeAllFiles(true); and that doesn't work with jQuery. Thanks.

Comment: @misley I think you are mixing things again, `removeAllFiles()` is a method that lives in the dropzone object or class. You can use dropzone methods from any initialization type you choose but only inside the init option, like in an event listener set up inside the init option, If you need a more detailed explanation on this topic you should open a new question about this.